# Cygwin locale for Russian/Russia

Tags: cygwin

On my Windows box, `locale` command outputs the following:

```
LANG=ru_RU
LC_CTYPE="ru_RU"
LC_NUMERIC="ru_RU"
LC_TIME="ru_RU"
LC_COLLATE="ru_RU"
LC_MONETARY="ru_RU"
LC_MESSAGES="ru_RU"
LC_ALL=
```

This is perfectly fine, except that "no charset" in the locale output means "ISO charset", which is `ISO-8859-5` for Russian/Russia and has never been used (historically, DOS used `CP866`, Windows used `CP1251` ANSI codepade, and various Unices sticked to `KOI8-R` before the rise of Unicode era).

The above is consistent with `locale charmap` output, which is again `ISO-8859-5`.

Short C example also confirms `ISO-8859-5` is used:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include <locale.h>
#include <langinfo.h>

int main() {
    const char *locale = setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
    const char *codeset = nl_langinfo(CODESET);
    printf("locale: %s\n", locale);
    printf("codeset: %s\n", codeset);

    return 0;
}
```

outputs

```
locale: ru_RU/ru_RU/ru_RU/ru_RU/ru_RU/C
codeset: ISO-8859-5
```

Cygwin docs [state](https://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/setup-locale.html) that

> Starting with Cygwin 1.7.2, the default character set is determined by the default Windows ANSI codepage for this language and territory.

which is plain wrong (Windows ANSI codepage is `CP1251`!). Surprisingly, for Belarusian (Eastern Slavic language very close to Russian) `be_BY` locale the default charset is indeed `CP1251` which is in accordance with both the documentation and common sense.

Is this a bug in Cygwin, or am I missing something here?

Comment: bugs should be reported on "cygwin (at) cygwin (dot) com"   see [link] (https://cygwin.com/cygwin/lists.html) . As interim you can set on your ".profile" the line "export LANG=$(locale -uU)" with your preference . I suggest "export LANG=ru_RU.UTF-8"

Comment: @matzeri: `$(locale -u)` returns `en_GB` for my English Windows 8.1 box, despite all regional settings are set to Russian/Russia. Requesting Unicode locale (`-U`) makes no sense, since this affects text file handling in a *Cygwin* shell launched from `cmd.exe` (`TERM=cygwin`). While *mintty* seems to ignore any locale settings (`cat`'ting a text file with ANSI Cyrillic always displays text correctly), plain `bash` launched from `cmd.exe` with raster fonts needs exactly `ru_RU.CP1251`.

Comment: have you tried to use "export LANG=ru_RU.UTF-8" or "export LANG=ru_RU.CP1251" ?

Comment: @matzeri: Yes, both `LANG` and `LC_ALL` are set to `ru_RU.CP1251`, and still `$(locale -u)` returns `en_GB`.

Comment: @matzeri: Additionally, in `strace locale -u` output, I see multiple `__get_lcid_from_locale: LCID=0x0419` lines. 0x0419 [corresponds](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318693%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) to Russian/Russia.